# Play video inside an app where that video is not bundled in the app

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, video

I have an app where I need to play a video but this video is not bundled inside my ipa file. The video is in video folder inside the iPad. How to call this video from my app and play it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UIImagePickerController to select from the ipad library.

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

picker.delegate = self;

picker.allowsEditing = YES;

picker.videoMaximumDuration = 10;

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

picker.mediaTypes =[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:imagePicker.sourceType];

UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
```

Try using similar sample code, above code is only a reference code. :)